# How can I create an upload-only folder in a document library?

Tags: permissions, file-upload

Our HR department wants users to download a form that requires a signature. They would like users to be able to scan those forms once completed and upload them to a folder.

These forms contain sensitive information. We want users to be able to upload, but they should not be able to view, download, modify or delete the files. Optimally, the user won't see their upload or any other uploads in the folder.

When creating a new permission level to accommodate this, I discovered that I can check "Add" but, sharepoint automatically checks "View". There does not appear to be a way to decouple this. As a result, I have a user group that can upload, but cannot modify or delete, but they and other users in that group can view and download the document.

How can I create an upload only folder in a document library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are better off storing documents in a document library which only authorized personnel can access. Even person who wants to upload the document does not have any rights on the library. This way you dont have to deal with permission maintenance and/or related issues.

So question is how do documents go there? I can think of one of the following:

1. [I would prefer this] Using Content Organizer Feature of SharePoint 2010. Check following:
   http://www.scottjamison.com/blog/2010/11/the-sharepoint-2010-content-organizer/. 
   Using this users can effectively add content into a place where they don’t have permissions.
2. Using a custom ASP.NET application page to upload the document to the library programatically. The code need to run under elevated priveleges, of course.
3. Have a document library in which users can upload the documents. Then have the documents moved to the target/secured location via batch job or workflows (you get the idea)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. #3 was the only one that had occurred to me -- I'll definitely look into Content Organizer. (I'm new to SharePoint.)

Answer (score 0):

Third Party addons for Column Level Permissions can solve the issue very easily. Most notably, [Bewise addon](http://splistdisplaysetting.codeplex.com/) - a free app available at Codeplex has a feature to decouple 'View' and 'Add'. However, the app works on Pre-Sharepoint 2010 versions only. Alternatively, Smart List Pro from Infowise Solutions is also great app.